# Transferring WinSCP configuration to macOS

Tags: terminal, ssh

I have been using Windows for a couple of decades, and just got a MacBook Pro.

Under Windows, I was using [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php), with PuTTY. I just installed [CyberDuck](https://cyberduck.io), and I know I should be able to use the built-in Mac Terminal, for PuTTY sessions. However, I would have to re-enter all the information (domain, login, password) every single time.

Any recommendations of what to use in macOS that can duplicate what I had with WinSCP, as close as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use ~/.ssh/config file.
In there you can set all your settings for a host etc.
For ssh you should not be using passwords, but keys instead.
by default ssh client on MacOS uses ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Some more info on that config file can be found [here](https://nerderati.com/2011/03/17/simplify-your-life-with-an-ssh-config-file/)

Some more info on ssh keys can be found [here](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/)

Or a little google search with those names will get you on route as well.

P.s. on the command line you can simply use `scp` (the thing that is ported to windows as WinSCP) to copy files from one place to another through ssh. Depends how much you depend on the GUI I guess.